# How to set the TWIML URL for an outbound TWIML call? - javascript and php

Tags: php, twilio

**Where do I tell Twilio to look for the `voice.php`  XML Twiml file?**

In a  twilio quickstart browser call app from a year and change ago there's a place in `quickstart.js` where you define your token URL.

```
$.getJSON('https://www.exa*****.com/voice/token.php')
```

in `token.php` is a place where you set the authorized Twilio number to be used as the "from" number in the `$TWILIO_CALLER_ID` variable.

Even though I had set these, uploaded, verified, ecetera... Twilio was requesting the `voice.php` XML from a different URL I had used in a previous application I had worked on. I can't find any reference to in the code and I can't tell where to set it on the account.

[image]

**Where do I tell Twilio to look for the `voice.php`  XML Twiml file?**

ANSWER:

https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/runtime/twiml-apps

I searched my console and couldn't find the answer but after a couple hours of aimlessly clicking in the Twilio dasboard I found the setting labeled under "TwiML Apps".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Access/Capability token references a TwiML Application SID you set up in the Twilio Console which points to a Voice URL which is where you set the CallerID. You can decode the token at https://jwt.io  (viewable from the browser console using the QuickStart) to see the Application SID.

Comment: If anyone needs the easy answer, please read the bottom of my question.

Comment: if you have any input in the Twilio dashboard layout, it would be helpful if things were a little easier to find. I couldn't understand why twiml apps would be under phone numbers and not run time. The bar on the left has a link for phone numbers and run time. Who would think to look for an app under phone numbers?
RUNTIME:
Functions
Studio
Assets
TwiML Bins
Sync
API Explorer
Debugger